# Qualitative analysis of differential equations $dx/dt = (a-x)x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given $dx/dt = (a-x)x^2$, where $a$ is a real number. How should $a$ be chosen to guarantee that every solution starting with $x(0) < 0$ will decrease?

If a were defined then I would just find the equilibrium points and plot the phase and solutions line/curve.

I am not sure how to go about solving $a$ in this scenario though.

Can anyone provide some advice or a tip?

Comment: Solve the ODE..

Comment: Welcome to MSE. To get better response show your work and also indicate where you stuck.

Comment: Just plot the solutions for arbitrary $a$, and do it separately when $a=0$. Nothing changes in the procedure.

Comment: @innerproduct: No, don't solve the ODE, that's unnecessary work! Just sketch the phase portrait by looking at the sign of the right-hand side.

Comment: Are you sure you quoted the question correctly? No matter what $a$ is, if $x(0)<0$ and $x(0)<a$, then the right-hand side is positive, so the solution increases. So there is no number $a$ satisfying the requirement.

Comment: @HansLundmark yip i definitely quoted correctly.  Might be an error in the question because I am reaching the same conclusion.